# Is there any way to make setter more reusable in Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

Here is my code:

```js
class Tooltip extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  }

  set position(boundingClientRect) {
    this.style.setProperty('--position', checksth(boundingClientRect));
    this.style.setProperty('--left', "0px")
    this.style.setProperty('--right', "0px")
    this.style.setProperty('--bottom', boundingClientRect.y + 100 + "px" )
  }

  // render HTML
  ...
}

customElements.define('x-tooltip', Tooltip)
```

and then I'am calling it on other js file

```js
const tooltip = document.createElement('x-tooltip')
tooltip.position = document.querySelector('.hover-over').getBoundingClientRect()
document.body.appendChild(tooltip)
```

The problem is I have an other tooltip that pretty similar to `Tooltip` component except the position style (might be shown at the top right concer, top left corner, bottom left corner...). One possible solution is to create a new Class like `TopLeftTooltip`, `TopRightTooltip` that extends `Tooltip` override the setter, but I don't want to create multiple component, is that any more clever solution?

Comment: I was unable to comprehend the problem correctly. Is your other tooltip defined in another class? How is that defined?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan right now, I don't have other tooltips. I want to create a bottom-right tooltip that have slightly different position styles. I might need to create different tooltip with different position later on.

Comment: You may create another setter function in the same class that takes in much more generic values for position, and configure your other tooltips using that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to building a house; put on your architect hat before you start piling bricks.

Design your HTML element and attributes **before** you dive into JS code:

`<x-tooltip><x-tooltip>`

`<x-tooltip position="topleft"><x-tooltip>`

`<x-tooltip position="bottomright"><x-tooltip>`

Then make it work with JS code.

The architect in me would not pass a position, instead pass the element the tooltip is a tooltip for. Keep the position logic inside the tooltip.